# Does Diablo III have a loot filter?

Tags: diablo-iii

Another ARPG, [Grim Dawn](https://store.steampowered.com/app/219990/Grim_Dawn/), has a "loot filter" feature which disables the text labels and being able to pick up loot below a specified level of rarity. Does Diablo III have any comparable feature?

Answer (score 9):

No, there is no loot filter for Diablo 3

Comment: There is on/off for item texts/icons though

Comment: There is a toggle for loot text / icon. But not a filter.

Comment: Note: The goblin ring will auto pick up white items and drop a blue once in a while, which works wonders at saving inventory space and works as a pre-endgame loot filter.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, a legendary item called [Puzzle Ring](https://us.diablo3.blizzard.com/en-us/item/puzzle-ring-Unique_Ring_004_x1) has since been added to the game.

> Summon a treasure goblin who picks up normal-quality items for you. After picking up 16 items, he drops a rare item with a chance for a legendary.

Additionally [the season 28](https://us.diablo3.blizzard.com/en-us/blog/23897180/season-28-rites-of-sanctuary-now-live-2-17-2023) introduced the 'Altar of Rites' object which requires unlocking a seal with somewhat extensive resource demands; its effect:

> Pets pick up and salvage common, magic, and rare items.

another related seal:

> Pets pick up [Death's Breath](https://us.diablo3.blizzard.com/en-us/item/deaths-breath-Crafting_Looted_Reagent_01) [a crafting material].

Both methods allow automating the collecting-and-salvaging process, while a basic 'loot filter' would only hide the dropped loot and leave their resources behind forever.

Unfortunately, there's no guarantee that the feature will be retained after the season ends ends on August, 2023.

[image: 'Altar of Rites' menu screenshot]